# Fixed background image shifts with negative margin on child

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```css
.top {
  background-color: Red;
  height: 200px;
}

.middle {
  background-color: Yellow;
  height: 200px;
}

.inner-middle {
  background-color: Aqua;
  height: 200px;
  margin: -50px 25px 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
</div>
<div class="middle">
  <div class="inner-middle">
  </div>
</div>
```

The code produces this layout:

[image]

I want to put a fixed background image on the middle div, to do so, I add a new class to the **middle** div.

```
.fixed-bg {
    background-image:url(/assets/images/map.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

However, the result is not what I expected. Here's an image:

[image]

As you can see, the parent is pulled up along with the child.

I can fix this using position relative instead of a negative margin. I could also look at moving the image to a different level. However, as I'm working to some already defined classes, I want to try and keep it as vanilla as possible.

Is there a magic tweak I can add to this code to stop the image from moving up?

Comment: Your code produces no visible output, please make [mcve] that we can test.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution, but one option could be adding `background-position: 50px center`. The top position should be equal to the top margin of the inner-middle div